# assigning array values and calculation are wrong

Tags: java

Q: Calculating the monthly units of electricity and getting the payment for every month.

1. I am not getting jan, feb, march so on payment correctly. Monthly payments should be seperate.
   110 = jan , 88 = feb and so on. If jan is less than 40, the value should multiply by 20.
2. example: if jan = 35 then 35 *20 = to payment which is 700. So this should be applied for all months.
3. int array jan, feb, march, april, may, jun, july, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec.

```java
class test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int months[] = {110, 88, 125,168,210,65,75,98,133,165,175,189};
        int x, size, count;
        size = months.length;
        double rate_chrg=0, payment =0;
        count = 0;
        x= 0;

        while (x<size){
            if (months[x] <40){
                payment = months[x] * 20;

            }
            else if(months[x] <60){
                payment = months[x] * 30;

            }
            else if(months[x] <80){
                payment = months[x] * 40;
            }
            else if(months[x] <250){
                payment = months[x] * 60;
            }
            x++;
        }

        System.out.println("Jan => " + months[0] + " = " +payment);
        System.out.println("Feb => " + months[1] + " = "+  payment);

    }
}
```

this is my output:

```
Jan => 110 = 11340.0
Feb => 88 = 11340.0
```

the amount amount is wrong, it should be printed like  `Jan => 110 = 6600`
 the above Answer 6000 is from 110 * 60 =6600

Comment: please hep i ahve used the java coding

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("Jan => " + months[0] + " = " +payment);
System.out.println("Feb => " + months[1] + " = "+  payment);
```

put those line inside the `while` loop, and you will see the different, the problem is `payment` will be re-initial again after each loop in `while`

Comment: yes you are right is being re-initiated every time like this:  Jan => 110 = 6600.0
Feb => 88 = 6600.0
Jan => 110 = 5280.0
Feb => 88 = 5280.0
Jan => 110 = 7500.0
Feb => 88 = 7500.0
Jan => 110 = 10080.0
Feb => 88 = 10080.0
Jan => 110 = 12600.0
Feb => 88 = 12600.0
Jan => 110 = 2600.0
Feb => 88 = 2600.0
Jan => 110 = 3000.0
Feb => 88 = 3000.0
Jan => 110 = 5880.0
Feb => 88 = 5880.0
Jan => 110 = 7980.0
Feb => 88 = 7980.0
Jan => 110 = 9900.0
Feb => 88 = 9900.0
Jan => 110 = 10500.0
Feb => 88 = 10500.0
Jan => 110 = 11340.0
Feb => 88 = 11340.0

Answer (score 0):

for January only this check

```
else if(months[x] <250)
```

is true, but this check is also true for March, April, May, September, October, November and December and because is iterating over the whole *months* array the payment is equal with the last element from the array which is only less the 250, which is December. So the payment it is 189*60

You need to either accumulate the payment or print the payment in the while loop

Answer (score 0):

int months[] = {110, 88, 125,168,210,65,75,98,133,165,175,189};
    String m[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Augest", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    int x, size, count, len;
    size = months.length;
    len = m.length;
    double payment =0;

```
x= 0;
count = 0;


  while (x<size && count<= len){
        if (months[x] <40){
          payment = months[x] * 20;

        }
        else if(months[x] <60){
          payment = months[x] * 30;
        }
        else if(months[x] <80){
          payment = months[x] * 40;
       }
       else if(months[x] <250){
         payment = months[x] * 60;
      }

      System.out.println(m[count] + ": "+ months[x] + " = " +payment);
      x++;
      count++;
}
```

// thank you and i did it... :)